# Mail.app import from Entourage failed

Tags: mail.app, import, ms-office

I am trying to import my entire folder structure from Entourage 2008 to Mail on a Mac running OS X 10.5.8.

First I tried to export the whole email database from Entourage to the Desktop as a .rge file. The export aborted with a message saying that my Entourage database is corrupt and that I should rebuild it.

I then went over to Mac Mail and imported the Entourage folder structure through **File > Import mailboxes… > Entourage**. The bulky import did take some time and the progress bar never reached its full length, but at the end the import said it was successful.

When I checked the imported folder structure in Mail I noticed that quite a few subfolders were missing. I checked Console and saw following message:

```
Mail[2899] Applescript Error: 
  aliasForMailImporter got an error: 
  AppleEvent handler failed.
```

What does that mean and what can I do to move my subfolder structure over completely?

Comment: Sounds like your Entourage file is, as it stated, corrupt. You may have to migrate your mail using an intermediate IMAP server. That way your mail folders and formatting will be retained.

Comment: @dori if the Question would be associated with my account I could mark your answer as accepted

Comment: you could also recreate the question which would allow us to merge the answers into it and give you ownership of it.

Comment: recreated it at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6047/2336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the message saying that your Entourage database is corrupt and needs to be rebuilt, I have to guess that your Entourage database is corrupt and recommend that you rebuild it.

As the saying goes, "Garbage in, garbage out."

Here are the directions on how to [rebuild your Entourage database](http://www.entourage.mvps.org/database/rebuild.html).

Comment: Thanx for the associating, seems that this is or making the import by hand was the only solution

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you're dealing with a corrupt Entourage database.  Rebuild it.  I suggest then using the Jolly Roger script to export all of your mail.  Find it here... http://jollyroger.kicks-ass.org/software/ArchiveMessageFolders.zip

Then you can import the structure by using the import feature in Mail.app.  Select the most parent folder that has been exported, and it will drop down to all of the subfolders automatically.

Good luck.